# Excel - Auto-update a date every week

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a small problem with Excel, I'm actually creating a planning for cleaning rooms.
I want the date to auto-update every week

Example of planning:
[image: Example of planning]

I want that the cell with 01/10/22 to be 07/10/2022 and others cells auto-update too (here it's simple I just have to do first date + 7)

But here the problem is with the first cell (01/10/2022).

What to do if I want this cell to update weekly?

My planning is starting on 01/10/2022, but when this day will pass, excel will have to add a week to the first cell which is 08/10/2022. the other cells will follow automatically –

The expected result after 01 October 2022 will pass :

first cell : 08/10/2022
Second cell : 15/10/2022
etc...

Comment: My planning is starting at 01/10/2022, but when this day will, When this day will pass, excel will have to add a week to the first cell which is 08/10/2022.
the other cells will follow automatically

Comment: Assuming you want the Monday of the current week, the following formula should work: `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)`. Side note: better to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1744612/edit) instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for your help. I want the Saturday of the current week, I don't see what I need change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Saturday of the current week, you can use the following formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1)=7,TODAY(),TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1))
```

Comment: Thanks it work for me!

Comment: Then please mark the answer as correct